# Making a dice game as my first Python project!

Tags: python, random, dice

I just started my programming lessons in school today and I decided to start learning more at home. This is my first day and I know the basics of `if` conditions, `for` and `while` loops and variables.

I decided to start my dice game project and the point of the game is to have 2 players competing against each other and different combinations will reward you with points. My goal is to create a game where each round each player will roll 5 dice and you will be able to get points from rolling a pair (higher pair = more points), three of a kind, straights and a full house.

So far I managed to create a game where each player gets to roll three dice and if you manage to roll a pair you will be rewarded with one point. The system works so far and in the end the program will decide a winner, but I have some problems.

I need some help with figuring out how to implement a system where different pairs give different points, a pair of 2 gives you two points and so on. I also have some problem with the three of a kind feature, every time I hit it I also hit a pair so it will only add one point because it is earlier in the `if` conditions.
Straights and full house's is also something that I'm not sure how to implement.
I would also be very happy to hear if you guys have anything that you would do different and why. I am new to this and I want to improve the code in any possible way.

### The Code

```
import random
import time

player1 = 0
player2 = 0

rounds_to_play = 4

for round_number in range(1, rounds_to_play, 1):
    print("Round", round_number, "is about to start!")
    time.sleep(2)
    roll = input("Player 1, are you ready to throw your dice? (y/n)")
    if roll == "y":
        while roll == 'y':
            print('Rolling the dice...')
            time.sleep(.5)

            dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
            dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
            dice3 = random.randint(1, 6)

            print("You rolled:")
            print(dice1, dice2, dice3)
            time.sleep(1)

            if dice1 == dice2 or dice1 == dice3 or dice2 == dice3:
                print("Well done! You rolled a pair (1p)")
                player1 = player1 + 1
                print("Player 1:", player1)
            elif dice1 == dice2 == dice3:
                print("WOW! You hit a three of a kind! (5p)")
                player1 = player1 + 5
                print("Player 1:", player1)
            else:
                print("Unlucky, you missed!")

            roll = 0
    else:
        print("Wow")

    time.sleep(5)

    roll = input("Player 2, are you ready to throw your dice? (y/n)")
    if roll == "y":
        while roll == 'y':
            print('Rolling the dice...')
            time.sleep(.5)

            dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
            dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
            dice3 = random.randint(1, 6)

            print("You rolled:")
            print(dice1, dice2, dice3)
            time.sleep(1)

            if dice1 == dice2 or dice1 == dice3 or dice2 == dice3:
                print("Well done! You rolled a pair (1p)")
                player2 = player2 + 1
                print("Player 2:", player2)
            elif dice1 == dice2 == dice3:
                print("WOW! You hit a three of a kind! (5p)")
                player2 = player2 + 5
                print("Player 2:", player1)
            else:
                print("Unlucky, you missed!")

            roll = 0
    else:
        print("Wow")

    time.sleep(3)

print("Calculating who the winner is...")
time.sleep(3)
if player1 > player2:
    print("Player 1 is the winner!")
elif player2 > player1:
    print("Player 2 is the winner!")
else:
    print("It's a draw!")
```

Comment: Nice! I don’t have time for a full answer now, but consider sorting the five dice values rolled. It is then much easier to see if you have a pair or three of a kind, because the equal values will be next to each other. For this, you need to put the rolled dice values into a list, rather than separate variables. Every time you have names like `dice1`, `dice2`, etc, it is time to replace them with a list so you can do `dice[0]`, `dice[1]`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

## Bug: Dice Pair vs 3 of a Kind

The condition:

```py
if dice1 == dice2 or dice1 == dice3 or dice2 == dice3:
```

evaluates as `True` for 3 of a kind, so this should be after `dice1 == dice2 == dice3`:

```py
if dice_1 == dice_2 == dice_3:
    # do things
elif dice_1 == dice_2 or ...:
    # other things
```

## Don't Repeat Yourself: Functions

You can see that in your player1 and player2 blocks, the code is about the same. This is a great place to introduce functions for repeatedly executed code:

```py
def roll_dice():
    print('Rolling the dice...')
    time.sleep(.5)

    a, b, c = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(3)]

    if a is b is c:
        print("Three of a kind! (5 points)")
        return 5
    elif a is b or a is c or b is c:
        print('You rolled a pair! (1 point)')
        return 1
        
    print("Unlucky, you missed! (0 points)")
    return 0
```

Let's return the score so that you can just add that to the user's score. Note that I'm using a list comprehension to build your dice rolls and unpacking that into each die.

## Use a Container for player state

Let's use a dictionary to contain each player and their score:

```py
players = {'player_1': 0, 'player_2': 0}
```

Then, when you add the score, you can do:

```py
players[player] += score
```

To show how this works:

```py
for player in players:
    score = roll_dice()
    players[player] += score
```

This also shows that you can iterate through the players rather than hand-coding each block.

## You don't need `step=1` in `range`

It's good to know that the argument exists for it, but it's `1` by default

## `__name__ == "__main__"` guard

These are nice to have when you start to write modules/code that you might want to import and reuse without the whole program executing:

```py
~snip~

# this is at the bottom
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

While we're here, let's introduce a `main` function to play the game:

```py
def main():
    rounds_to_play = 4
    players = {'Player 1': 0, 'Player 2': 0}

    for i in range(rounds_to_play):
        print(f"Starting round {i}")

        for player in players:
            players[player] += roll_dice()

    print('Calculating winner...')
    time.sleep(3)

    # unpack from the dictionary
    (name_1, score_1), (name_2, score_2) = players.items()

    if score_1 > score_2:
        print(f"{name_1} wins!")
    elif score_1 == score_2:
        print("Draw!")
    else:
        print(f"{name_2} wins!")
```

## `sys` args

It might be nice to pass the number of rounds (or even the number of players) as a command-line argument:

```py
def main(num_rounds):
    players = {'Player 1': 0, 'Player 2': 0}

    for i in range(num_rounds):
        # rest of function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_rounds, *_ = sys.argv[1:]
    main(int(num_rounds))
```

This is a pretty simple way to do it, you could also look into [`argparse.ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answer, i will try to implement these things later today!

Answer (score 0):

Starting to learn at home is an excellent idea.

### The code

It's not a great idea to hard-code score values for two players (and `playern` is not an obvious name for a score value variable). Better off using `Counter`.

`time.sleep` is anywhere from an annoyance ('about to start') to an outright lie ('calculating who the winner is', when no such calculation is being done - it's just sleeping). To pace the progress of the program, you could wait for a keypress - and I don't mean "are you ready to throw your dice? (y/n)", which... doesn't make sense. Why would a user ever say no? Instead, consider *Press any key when you are ready to throw your dice*.

You can use a comprehension to roll multiple dice into a list.

`player1 = player1 + 1` is just `player1 += 1`.

`while roll == 'y'` doesn't make any sense, because you're only ever iterating once, and then setting your loop variable unconditionally at the end of the loop - get rid of the loop.

Lots of other things to learn, but this (and suggestions from C.Nivs) are a good start.

### The game

This is sort of like the infamous [Candy Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_Land) in that there are never actually any decisions made.

Consider spicing it up - what if the player decided whether to roll to increase their score, but with a risk that their round's score could be lost? (Something like double-or-nothing.)

### Suggested

Other than the 'press any key' suggestion:

```py
import random
from collections import Counter

n_players = 2
n_rounds = 4
n_dice = 3
points = Counter()

for round_number in range(n_rounds):
    print(f'Round {round_number+1}:')
    for player in range(n_players):
        dice = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n_dice)]
        print('  Player', player+1, 'rolled', ', '.join(str(d) for d in dice))

        match len(set(dice)):
            case 1:
                print('    WOW! You hit a three of a kind!', end=' ')
                round_points = 5
            case 2:
                print('    Well done! You rolled a pair', end=' ')
                round_points = 1
            case _:
                print('    Unlucky, you missed!', end=' ')
                round_points = 0

        print(f'({round_points}p)')
        points[player] += round_points
    print()

(_, hiscore), = points.most_common(1)
match [player for player, point in points.items() if point == hiscore]:
    case (winner,):
        print(f'Player {1+winner} is the winner with {hiscore} points!')
        print()
    case winners:
        print("It's a draw between players", ', '.join(str(p) for p in winners))
```

```
Round 1:
  Player 1 rolled 4, 1, 4
    Well done! You rolled a pair (1p)
  Player 2 rolled 6, 2, 6
    Well done! You rolled a pair (1p)

Round 2:
  Player 1 rolled 2, 2, 4
    Well done! You rolled a pair (1p)
  Player 2 rolled 6, 4, 1
    Unlucky, you missed! (0p)

Round 3:
  Player 1 rolled 3, 3, 3
    WOW! You hit a three of a kind! (5p)
  Player 2 rolled 3, 3, 2
    Well done! You rolled a pair (1p)

Round 4:
  Player 1 rolled 2, 3, 4
    Unlucky, you missed! (0p)
  Player 2 rolled 1, 4, 5
    Unlucky, you missed! (0p)

Player 1 is the winner with 7 points!
```